# Report spam to Gmane?

Tags: gnus

I am lost in Gnus documentation.

How can I report spam to Gmane when read Gmane NNPP in Gnus?

I set:

```
(with-eval-after-load gnus-art
   (setq gnus-visible-headers (concat gnus-visible-headers "\\|^Archived-At:\\|^List-URL:")))
```

in order to visit web page and push report button manually.

My attempt is:

```
(with-eval-after-load gnus
  (require 'spam)
  (spam-initialize)
  (setq gnus-spam-process-newsgroups
        '(("^gmane\\." ((spam spam-use-gmane))))))
```

but I am unsure if this is correct way and if that worked at all.

Comment: You can check by monitoring if http-requests to gmane.org are made when you exit a gmane-group (i.e. using "ngrep -Wbyline port 80" or wireshark or tcpdump or similar).

Comment: The first argument to `with-eval-after-load` should be probably be quoted `'gnus` unless you have a variable `gnus` whose value is ... that symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I have set these parameters on my [Gmane]-topic:

```
((spam-process
  ((spam spam-use-gmane)))
 (spam-summary-exit-behavior 'move-none)
 (spam-use-hashcash nil)
 (spam-use-crm114 nil))
```

The last two are "just to be sure", to turn off hashcash and crm114, which I have turned on globally (I think).